# Intelligent news feed software

Tags: web-apps, feed-reader

I read news mostly online. So I bookmarked and pinned many news website through times. I have also countless RSS feeds and Google news alerts in my mail.

All these are good but navigating through them became very time consuming. The main problem is the time I need to select the information that interests me. For example, RSS brings directly to me many articles from the same source but poorly discriminates between interesting and non-interesting topics (sometimes you can specialized as "Times - Sport" instead of just "Times" but it is still limited). Or Google News Alert brings to my emails box many articles but many irrelevant ones too (e.g. "maths" will bring ads for maths tutoring"). Also, Google does not know which journals I consider serious and which ones are not.

Sorry for this long introduction but I think that explaining what is a problem with the numerous existing solutions helps better than a requirement list.

So, here is what I am looking for: a clever software that would learn which topics I like and which journals I prefer. YouTube does it relatively well for videos, and Facebook and Google ads target me very accurately, so I guess there is a hope!

More precise requirements:

1. Windows 10
2. I would prefer an online application than installing a software on my computer. My browsers are Chrome and Firefox. Internet Explorer if the two other ones cannot be used. I would prefer to register to a website rather than adding a module in my browser.
3. No smartphone only applications please.
4. Free or cheap subscription.
5. I don't mind if the software isn't really precise at first. Convenience is more important than efficiency at the beginning.

Comment: Does the filtering process have to be automatic, or can the application use user-defined filters and rules the way email clients do?

Comment: I don't have definitive opinion on that matter. Automatic with a possible of filters (user-defined filter is the simplest and most efficient to completely ban sources I don't like)

Comment: There are two alternatives you may like. None will completely match your needs but both are really good and have uses. Feedly (http://feedly.com) is the best rss tool i can find after serious research. It keeps your sources well organized and have web client as well as several mobile client options ( i use Newsify on ios find it a better alternative then native feedly client). Feedly doesnt make any filtering as you want. Here comes the second alternative. Flipboard ( https://flipboard.com/). Flipboard with filtering but acts more like composer. You can fine tune this one though.

Answer (score 2):

[Thunderbird](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/thunderbird/) has decent RSS support, but no direct way to indicate "interesting" vs "boring". However, if you install [TaQuilla](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/thunderbird/addon/taquilla/) and add one or more smart tags ("interesting - sports", "interesting - maths" — the easier it is for you to judge them, the better the system will work), TB can start using text classification to figure out which sorts of articles you like. There *will* be an initial ramp-up during which you will need to mark various articles as "definitely interesting sports" or "definitely not", and you'll want to keep marking occasional misjudged articles in roughly even proportions as you go, but with some time put in, it should do a pretty solid job. I've been using TaQuilla for email tagging for some years now, and it's pretty good, especially after tweaking its options a bit.

(Thunderbird also supports fairly sophisticated manual filtering on RSS feeds, if you need that too.)